# How to make NSView's background image not repeat?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want replicate the effect obtained by the following CSS code:

```
background: white url(./img/background.png) no-repeat;
```

I've written a subclass of NSView and override `drawRect` in this way:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    dirtyRect = [self bounds];

    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

(I apologize for my bad english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `NSImage` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Image can be drawn with [drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/drawInRect%3afromRect%3aoperation%3afraction%3a) and also with [drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/drawAtPoint%3afromRect%3aoperation%3afraction%3a).

So You can Use this:

```
[[NSImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1]; // Passing NSZeroRect causes the entire image to draw.
```

Instead this:

```
[[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
```

Comment: Just to add something for beginners (like myself): You can add the first line in the `drawRect:` method of your custom NSView subclass. The result is that the `background.png` will be drawn as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:` to draw your image in the view instead of filling your rect with a pattern color.