# NSColor colorWithPatternImage: Vs. NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsimage

So I'm trying to set the background of a view as an image, and I read in another thread that to avoid repeating the image, one should use `NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:` rather than `NSColor colorWithPatternImage:` However, when I use the former the image doesn't draw in the view, while it works with the latter (but repeats, which I don't want). Is there something I'm missing here? The image is in the Images.xcassets folder and I implemented both methods as suggested in the other thread here: [How to make NSView's background image not repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231874/how-to-make-nsviews-background-image-not-repeat)

Here's my code:

```
#import "OrangeBGView.h"

@implementation OrangeBGView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];//To easily see if image isn't loading
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"orangeGradientBGWithTopEdgeShadow.png"]] setFill];//Working
//    [[NSImage imageNamed:@"orangeGradientBGWithTopEdgeShadow.png"] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];//Not working
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

}

@end
```

Comment: there is no point in calling super here since you are clobbering whatever it does with your fill. Show us the code where you try using `NSImage` and `drawInRect:` please.

Comment: @BradAllred Okay, thanks. Took out the super. The `drawInRect:` line is the commented line below the `colorWithPatternImage:` so that code would just be the same thing but with the `colorWithPatternImage:` line commented and the `drawInRect:` line active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple oversight on my part. the `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:` was working fine, but I left in the last `NSRectFill(dirtyRect)` line, which essentially painted over the image I was drawing. This code now works:

```
#import "OrangeBGView.h"

@implementation OrangeBGView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];//To easily see if image isn't loading
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    [[NSImage imageNamed:@"orangeGradientBGWithTopEdgeShadow.png"] drawInRect:dirtyRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
}

@end
```